# Joomla user authorization with external SSO

Tags: joomla

I am **trying to integrate a Joomla website with an internal Single Signon System**.  The SSO user authentication & authorization system was home grown and handles all of our user access.

I have an SSO website that I would like to send all Joomla users to, once they are authenticated they will be re-rerouted back to the Joomla website and they would be logged in.

What I need to be able to do is set a session variable and check this session id against our authentication server to see if the User session is still valid, essentially augmenting the Joomla Session / authorization check.  If the session is invalid, I would redirect the user to the SSO login page.

Is there a core Joomla event that I can attach to that would allow be to perform authorization also??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a high level overview where you can do some things.

There are two events which you can use to trigger and to intercept the authentication process.

As a **system plugin**, using `onAfterInitialise()` you can trigger very early in the execution cycle an authentication request:

```
    // Get the application object.
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $result = $app->login($credentials, $options);
```

Basically when the user loads a page, if it does not already have a session / is a guest `JFactory::getUser()->guest === 1`, you can try to authenticate the user, based on whatever you like.

The request earlier triggered can be intercepted with a **authentication plugin**, implementing the method `onUserAuthenticate()`. Inside this method you can actually make a request to the external system by whatever means you like (see existing authentication plugins).

Comment: I would also go for this answer. Writing your own authentication plugin is the easiest way to be upgrade safe and not depend on other extensions fur such a small functionality.

Comment: This is what I had started doing, however, the system plugin is what I think I'll need to make it all work.

Comment: Thanks @Valentin Despa, this is going to get me where I need to go.

Comment: Is there a way to check if a user has registered, without being logged in?  I have tried JFactory::getUser('username'), however the method returns a user id of 0 unless I have logged in.  Have also tried JUserHelper::getUserId( 'username' ) to no avail.

Comment: You may want to post this as a standalone question. Check a plugin like "autologin after register" or set a cookie after registration.

Comment: Turns out I had a bug, so at least JUserHelper is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need an authentication bridge.

JFusion should allow you to do what you want.  As well as integrating with various existing systems it allows for a custom authentication bridge.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-bridges/3723